# Llamar a signalr hub desde una ventana modal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Estoy intentando desde una ventana modal llamar al hub pero no llega al hub, sin dar ningún error

Aquí el código:

-Funcion hub:

```
public void Estado(int estado, int id)
{
        RepositorioVisitas.AutorizarCancelarVisita(id,estado);
visitasMostradas.RemoveAll(d => d.IdVisita == id);

}
```

-Javascript:

```
<script>
        var visita;
        $(function () {

        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
         visita = $.connection.visitasHub;
        $('#nuevaFilaVisitas >tr').remove();
        //alert($('#nuevaFilaVisitas >tr').length);
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        visita.client.SendAlert = function (id, fechaI, fechaF, anfitrion, visitante, obse) {
            var nuevaFila = "<tr id='" + id + "'>"
            nuevaFila += "<td id='inicio'>" + fechaI + "</td>";
            nuevaFila += "<td id='fin'>" + fechaF + "</td>";
            nuevaFila += "<td id='anfitrion'>" + anfitrion + "</td>";
            nuevaFila += "<td id='visitantes'>" + visitante + "</td>";
            nuevaFila += "<td id='observaciones'>" + obse + "</td>";
            nuevaFila += "<td class='align-center'><ul class='table-controls'><li><a href='javascript:void(0)' id='opcionAceptar' class='bs-tooltip' data-original-title='Autorizar'><i class='icon-ok' style='color:green'></i></a></li></ul></td>";
            nuevaFila += "<td class='align-center'><ul class='table-controls'><li><a href='#' id='opcionCancelar' class='bs-tooltip' data-original-title='Cancelar'><i class='icon-remove' style='color:red'></i></a></li></ul></td></tr>";
            $('#nuevaFilaVisitas').append(nuevaFila);
            $('#modalVisitas').modal();
            $.playSound('/Hubs/Notification');

        };

        visita.client.reset = function () {
            $('#nuevaFilaVisitas >tr').remove();
            $("#modalVisitas").modal('hide');
            $.playSound('/Hubs/Notification');
        }



        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {visita.server.grupo($("#deptGrupo").val());});


        **$("#modalVisitas").on("click", "#opcionCancelar", function () {

            var idVisita = $("#opcionCancelar").closest("tr").attr("id");
            visita.server.estado(3, idVisita);
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            var numFilas = $('#nuevaFilaVisitas >tr').length;
            if (numFilas == 0) { $("#modalVisitas").modal('hide'); }
        })
        $("#modalVisitas").on("click", "#opcionAceptar", function () {
            var idVisita = $("#opcionCancelar").closest("tr").attr("id");
            visita.server.estado(3, idVisita);
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            var numFilas = $('#nuevaFilaVisitas >tr').length;
            if (numFilas == 0) { $("#modalVisitas").modal('hide'); }
        })**


        });



</script>
```

En la ultima parte es donde falla

```
$("#modalVisitas").on("click", "#opcionCancelar", function () {

            var idVisita = $("#opcionCancelar").closest("tr").attr("id");
            visita.server.estado(3, idVisita);
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            var numFilas = $('#nuevaFilaVisitas >tr').length;
            if (numFilas == 0) { $("#modalVisitas").modal('hide'); }
        })
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda

Comment: intenta esto, mete la parte donde falla, dentro de esta función `$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {`, porque aquí es donde la conexión esta establecida y puedas usar el método dentro del hub

Comment: Nada no llega  :(

Comment: tienes agregadas los scripts de signalR? `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>` `<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`

Comment: si los tengo agregados, de hecho todo funciona menos esa parte

Comment: Tengo la version 1.1.3 oprque en mvc 4.5 la 2 no me funcionaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo que hice fue desde la vista ir a un controlador y desde el controlador llamar al hub y así va perfecto